# Ignoring a file during merge and push

Tags: git, gitattributes

In my repository with two branches (master/develop) I have a sensitive file containing passwords and api keys that for obvious reasons cannot be pushed to the remote repository. This same file defines also port on which the app is running on develop and production stage (they are different). For this reason this file should be excluded from merging.

Putting it simply in `.gitignore` would make is unvisible to git and the content would have to be edited manually upon checkout. Is there a way to use `.gitattributes` so, that the requirements I mentioned (i.e. the file is ignored on merge and push but not on commit) are fullfilled?